# Слова наоборот, исправить ошибки

Tags: java

Я сделала программу, но есть маленький нюанс, который я никак не могу исправить. Задание короче такое. В консольной строке я задаю цифру которая обозначает количество обработанных предложений. Потом ввожу предложения, а программа должна увеличить все буквы и перевернуть слова задом на перед. Например    `"Привет, меня зовут Наташа" вывод:" ТЕВИРП, ЯНЕМ ТУВОЗ АШАТАН."` Да и обязательно в конце должна быть точка, но у меня она делается вместе с пробелом, это одно что я не могу исправить и второе, когда я ввожу количество предложений и нажимаю Enter, то это мне считает как уже задание предложение, а так не должно быть. Помогите пожалуйста исправить ошибки не сильно ломая мой задум. Да и обратите внимание на то что в предложении каждое слово отдельно переворачивается, а не все вместе, это важно.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TransformaceTextu 
{
    static Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int n = sc.nextInt();

        while( n != 0 ) {
            String text = sc.nextLine();
            text = text.toUpperCase();

            for (String slovo : text.split(" ")) {
                System.out.print(new StringBuilder(slovo).reverse().toString());                    
                System.out.print(" ");
            }
            System.out.println(".");
            n--;
        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: Не совсем понятно, что вы подразумеваете под словом "приложение".

Answer (score 1):

После `nextInt()` нужно вызвать `sc.nextLine()` чтобы считать символ ввода.

Answer (score 0):

1. чтобы ввод количества предложений не считался за предложение, надо считывать строку полностью. или как уже предлагали дополнительным `sc.nextLine` или без nextInt, т.е. `int n = Integer.parseInt(sc.nextLine());`
2. пробел перед точкой появляется потому что он у Вас выводится после каждого слова. Тут есть несколько решений (выбирайте какое из них не сильно сломает Вашу задумку):

   2.1. выводить пробел перед словом, если это не первое слово в предложении. для этого понадобится добавить булевую переменную в тело цикла while.

   2.2. изменять слова в том же массиве в который их распределил split, а потом выводить массив с помощью `String.join()`

   2.2.b тоже, но вместо того же массива, чтобы не ломать цикл for добавить List в который складывать перевернутые слова и выводить лист джойном

ну или если не боитесь радикально сломать "задум", самым изящным решением имхо было бы использовать стрим:

```
String text = sc.nextLine();
System.out.println(
  Arrays.stream(text.split(" "))
    .map(s -> new StringBuilder(s.toUpperCase()).reverse())
    .collect(java.util.stream.Collectors.joining(" ", "", ".")));
```

---

*update*

по Вашей просьбе, улучшаем распознавание пробелов:

используем `text.split("\\s+")` вместо `text.split(" ")`

как это работает: если Вы посмотрите в [документацию](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)), то увидите, что параметр это не просто строка, а регулярное выражение. т.о. Вы можете в качестве разделителя использовать не один пробел, а ряд невидимых символов (включая пробелы, табы и т.д. т.к. `\s` это предопределенный класс символов: `[ \t\n\x0B\f\r]`)

Comment: Все идеально, спасибо, но есть маленькая проблема. А если в предложении не один а три либо неизвестное количество пробелов, а в результате я хочу только один, но программа выдает все, что мне посоветуете?

Comment: **А если в предложении не один а три либо неизвестное количество пробелов** ссылка на документацию выдана, нужно мышкой на неё навести, и кнопочкой так "клик".